# Error connecting to database with JUnit

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, mariadb

The application, database connections, and SQL queries work fine once deployed on a Tomcat server. Trying to run some JUnit tests on the application and get the following error:

`ERROR [main] (DbConnectionTest.java:35) - Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

Here's the JUnit class

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

public class DbConnectionTest {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class);
    private static Connection con;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception{
        logger.info("Test started from DbConnectionTest...");
        con = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetConnection() {
        System.out.println("Running the getConnection");
        try{
            con = DbConnection.getConnection();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            fail("Failed to connect to the database");
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Test Ended DbConnectionTest...");
        if(con != null){
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method that it is testing:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/db");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
    }
```

I have a context.xml and web.xml file that are used for connecting to MariaDB when it's deployed on Tomcat. Not sure what the problem is when using JUnit.

**EDIT**

Now getting this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Caused by this method

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {

        // Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(); //Line causing error

        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

        // Construct DataSource
        MariaDbDataSource ds = new MariaDbDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306");
        ds.setUser("user");
        ds.setPassword("pass");

        ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/db", ds);

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        return conn;
    }
```

I'm using Eclipse, and this is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.<clinit>(NamingContext.java:60)
at org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.getInitialContext(javaURLContextFactory.java:112)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.prudential.connection.DbConnection.getConnection(DbConnection.java:35)
at com.prudential.tests.DbConnectionTest.testGetConnection(DbConnectionTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Have u solved this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a JNDI lookup, and if you're using JUnit without a JNDI context it won't work.

Take a look at this:

https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

You can create your connection and put it into the correct location in a test JNDI context in a `@Before` annotated method so it exists when you need to look it up.

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception{
        logger.info("Test started from DbConnectionTest...");
        con = null;
        logger.info(    "TODO: I need to create a database connection and JNDI 
                        "context and register a connection here, so that when my" +
                        " method tries to look it up it will work!"
                   );
}
```

Comment: Ok now I have this error when trying to create a new InitialContext: 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Comment: OK, that's no use unless you post how you're getting it.  At a minimum, post your code, how you're running it (Maven, IDE, whatever...) and your classpath.

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited my question above